# Did Allah keep Zayd's ex-wife for marriage to Muhammad? (Qur'an 33:6 and 33:37)

Tags: quran, tafseer, wives-of-the-prophet

Sura Ahzab-33 Ayat-37
And [remember, O Muhammad], when you said to the one on whom Allah 
bestowed favor and you bestowed favor, "Keep your wife and fear Allah," while you concealed within yourself that which Allah is to disclose. And 
you feared the people, while Allah has more right that you fear Him. **So when 
Zayd had no longer any need for her**, We married her to you in order that there not be 
upon the believers any discomfort concerning the wives of their 
adopted sons when they no longer have need of them. 
And ever is the command of Allah accomplished.

Sura Ahzab-33 Ayat-6
**The Prophet is more worthy of the believers than themselves, and 
his wives are [in the position of] their mothers**. And those of
[blood] relationship are more entitled [to inheritance] in the 
decree of Allah than the [other] believers and the emigrants, 
except that you may do to your close associates a kindness 
[through bequest]. That was in the Book inscribed.

The wives of The Prophet Muhammad SAW are mothers of Mominin in Ayat 6 and Ayat 37  when Zayd divorced his wife Allah kept her (the former wife of Zayd) in marriage Of Muhammad SAW? Please help me understand it..... what is full meaning of ayat in the context.

Comment: What exactly is troubling you? Do you think these two verses contradict each other?

Comment: Zayd bin Harith's Ex wife became wife of Muhammad SAW after divorce and the wives of Muhammad SAW are mothers of Mominin IN GENERAL. Does it not contradict if not will you please explain what is meant by declaring the wives of Muhammad SAW to be the mothers of mominin and Zayd was also momin cos' he also accepted Islam?  On one hand wives of Muhammad SAW are mothers of Mominin and on other side  Muhammad SAW marries her......! Thanks with prayer from Allah that He forgive me if I make any mistake.

Answer (score 3):

As @afnrf said it's not really clear what is troubling you! But i'll try to give an answer by interpretation the two Verses according to tafsir books:

**Verse 33/37**

Is talking about Zayd ibn Haritah (May Allah be pleased with him) and the Marriage of our Prophet (Peace be upon him) with his former wife Zaynab (May Allah be pleased with her): Zayd was adopted by our Messenger (Peace be upon him) in Jahilya, so everybody called him "Ibn Mohammad" till the revealing of the part of the Verse which "quotes" that adopted sons are no longer considered sons! Our Messenger (Peace be upon him) married him to his cousin (The daughter sister of the father of the Messenger Omaymah bin 'abd al-Muttalib) Zaynab bint Jahsh al-Assadiya (May Allah be pleased with her), but after one year of marriage they had a dispute (some say because she was considering her husband as base-born while she was a noble of Mekka) and Zayd went to our Messenger (Peace be upon him) to complain about her and our Messenger (Peace be upon him) told him:"Keep your wife and fear Allah" but at least they divorced and our Messenger has married her later. According to some Narrations (tafsir [ibn Kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1855&Itemid=89)) he already knew he will marry her one day that's why Allah said

> "while you concealed within yourself that which Allah is to disclose"

Now the difficulty was that Man couldn't marry their son's wives even in the case of an adopted son's according to the customs of Jahilya. So the words

> "We married her to you in order that there not be upon the believers any discomfort concerning the wives of their adopted sons when they no longer have need of them"

Made an end to this custom and declared that Adoption is not allowed in Islam or at least doesn't count as parenthood when it comes to shari'a! From that time on Zayd was no longer called Zayd ibn Mohammad but Zayd ibn Haritah!

According Tafsir ibn Kathir there's a narration in Musnad al Imam Ahmad telling that it was Zayd himself who was sent out from our Messneger (Peace be upon him) to ask her for marriage after the end of her 'idah! And [here](http://sunnah.com/muslim/16/105)'s a Version from Sahih Muslim.

For more details see this ahadith which give some information about the story:
In [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/47/259)

In [Sahih al Bukhari narrated by 'Aisha](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/48) and [Anas ibn Malik](http://sunnah.com/urn/181220)

**Verse 33/6**:

Is mentioning the Relation between the Messenger (Peace be upon him) and the believers and also the high position of his wife's, with which Allah has honored them!
As it's unclear what is troubling you i will just quote some ahadith which support the meaning of the Verse, but feel free to ask if you are looking for an explanation of an exact matter!

- The position and relationship of our Messenger for the believers:
  In [Sahih al Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/7) (but also quoted in other books with similar Words from different sahaba (May Allah be pleased with them) and an other [Narration](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/85/8) quoting a part of the Verse.
- "[*And those of [blood] relationship are more entitled [to inheritance]*](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/19/40)"
- For the part "*And his wives are [in the position of] their mothers*" their are many different interpretation, on what is the meaning of Umahat al-mu'minyn and to whom they are considered mothers which are described and discussed in tafsir books like [ibn Kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1871&Itemid=89), [al-Qurtobi](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2758&bk_no=48&flag=1) 
  (who quoted a statement of 'Aisha saying to a woman that she is only the mother of the male Muslims, al-Qurtobi rejects this and says that the mothers of believers are mothers for both male and female, he also discussed the matter whether looking at them is halal, as a mother is allowed to look at for her "children" as she is a mahram, so it's a question about the significance of mother and the mahram status, whether it only means one isn't allowed to marry them after his death or the "known" mahram status of a mother. He also discussed the status of woman our Prophet has divorced during his lifetime, so the most prevalent opinion in this is that if the marriage was consummated the status of mahram applies to her also, there's also the opinion that this applies to any woman he married or they are considered after the divorce as any other woman)
   and [at-tahrir wa at-tanwir](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2795&bk_no=61&flag=1) 
  (who added that woman whom were not his legal wives or with whom a marriage was consummated, so what his right hand posses and women to whom he got married to but divorced before the marriage was consummated are not considered as "mothers of believers") ...

Comment: "For the part "And his wives are [in the position of] their mothers" their are many different interpretation, on what is the meaning of Umahat al mu'minyn and to whom they are considered mothers which are described and discussed in tafsir books like ibn Kathir, al-Qurtobi and at-tahrir wa at-tanwir." This part is unclear to me

Comment: What is summary of This  Kathir, al-Qurtobi and at-tahrir wa at-tanwir about And his wives are [in the position of] their mothers"??? Plz share to understand it.......!

Comment: @Khalid i'm not sure if this will help -now without looking back in the tafsir books- you know that your mother is a woman which is for you a mahram, this means it's haram for you to marry her. And we know that nobody was allowed to marry the wife's of the Messenger of Allah(peace be upon him) as they are mother's of the believers. But you might find some ahadith quoting that 'Aisha asked her sister Asma' (May Allah be pleased with both of them) to feed those men who wanted to ask her about ahadith or fatwa. So she didn't interpret this verse as a equal with being mahram for them!

Answer (score 3):

The wives of the Holy Prophet (pbuh) became mothers of the believers ***after*** they got married to him. Before the marriage they were normal women with whom anyone could have married.

Declaring them mothers of the believers means that the believers should have the same respect and feelings for them that children have for their mothers ***and*** they should never think about marrying anyone of them; neither in the life nor after the death of the Holy Prophet. This aspect is clearly mentioned in the same chapter as well:

> It is not right for you to cause annoyance to the Messenger of God or
>   for you ever to marry his wives after him. [33:53](http://tanzil.net/#33:53)

Therefore, the marriage of the Zayd (ra) with Zaynab (ra) was perfectly fine. However, after her divorce and marriage to the Holy Prophet it was not lawful for anyone to marry her.

Comment: Therefore "the marriage of the Zayd (ra) with Zaynab (ra) was perfectly fine. However, after her divorce and marriage to the Holy Prophet it was not lawful for anyone to marry her." It's cleared but Question is confusing me that how come it be possible that past spouse after divorce became mother as Allah Al-mighty declares in Quran that one can not use even words of "You are like back of my mother" to effect talaq

Comment: 33-4Al-Quran "Arberry: God has not assigned to any man two hearts within his breast; nor has He made your wives, when you divorce, saying, 'Be as my mother's back,' truly your mothers, neither has He made your adopted sons your sons in fact. That is your own saying, the words of your mouths; but God speaks the truth, and guides on the way.

Comment: No one can marry as it is prohibited for momonin to even think of marrying the wives of Holy prophet saw during or after the life of Muhammad saw. It's cleared

Comment: Simply my question is how one can call or consider her spouse to be his mother even after divorce and marriage with other....??? Positively asked there is no negative intention or any ulterior motive to ask this question it is only for understanding.